# Baxter_Gazebo: can't get current joint states

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Installed Baxter Simulator as per the instructions. When I run any of the python programs to allow the robot to do anything, I get something like the example below:

```
$ rrun baxter_examples joint_position_waypoints.py -l right Initializing node...  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pipothy/ros_ws/src/baxter_examples/scripts/joint_position_waypoints.py", line 191, in <module>
    main()   File "/home/pipothy/ros_ws/src/baxter_examples/scripts/joint_position_waypoints.py", line 181, in main
    waypoints = Waypoints(args.limb, args.speed, args.accuracy)   File "/home/pipothy/ros_ws/src/baxter_examples/scripts/joint_position_waypoints.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._limb = baxter_interface.Limb(self._arm)   File "/home/pipothy/ros_ws/src/baxter_interface/src/baxter_interface/limb.py", line 121, in __init__
    timeout_msg=err_msg)   File "/home/pipothy/ros_ws/src/baxter_interface/src/baxter_dataflow/wait_for.py", line 55, in wait_for
    raise OSError(errno.ETIMEDOUT, timeout_msg) OSError: [Errno 110] Right limb init failed to get current joint_states from robot/joint_states
```

I can't seem to find why. I can echo the topic and get data from it. Only unusual thing is the /robot/state/ says "Ready: False". Any idea why this might be?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19035/baxter_gazebo:-can%27t-get-current-joint-states/) by [pipothy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4898/pipothy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2018-04-17**:
A couple of comments: it can help to provide people with the instructions to reproduce the problem. There is an official Rethink github for Baxter, it might be a better place to debug the problem https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/baxter/issues

**Comment by [pipothy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4898/pipothy/) on 2018-04-17**:
Thanks for your advice. I will mention exactly what I did:

I already had ROS installed, but other than that, I followed the installation instructions at the link below line by line. I used the commands for kinetic and stopped after launching the baxter world:
http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation
I then enabled the robot using ran a command to start an example:
http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Joint_Position_Waypoints_Example
This produced the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The people over at baxter simulator have been able to solve this issue.

It's due to the models not loading properly as they need to be downloaded when you launch the world. So, if you relaunch the world, it fixed the issue for me.

---

Originally posted by [pipothy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4898/pipothy/) with karma: 26 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1